# New project and old Core Data Model

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I do have an existing project with a Core Data model. I am trying to run a new project (on top of the old model) and read what it's in the model itself.

Now, the app runs smoothly on top of the previous one. I have imported the .xcdatamodeld and nothing is crashing. However when I try to get some values from an Entity that should have some (since I have loaded it before from the old project), I get 0 as results.

I am new to Core Data, so I might be missing something really simple.

This is my current persistentStoreCoordinator (which I have found here: [Coredata after Application Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790558/coredata-after-application-update)):

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Model"];
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [self managedObjectModel];
    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: managedObjectModel];

    // Check if we already have a persistent store
    if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [storeURL path]] ) {
        NSLog(@"We have a persistent store!");
        NSDictionary *existingPersistentStoreMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType: NSSQLiteStoreType URL: storeURL error: &error];
        if ( !existingPersistentStoreMetadata ) {
            // Something *really* bad has happened to the persistent store
            //[NSException raise: NSInternalInconsistencyException format: @"Failed to read metadata for persistent store %@: %@", storeURL, error];
            NSLog(@"Failed to read metadata for persistent store %@: %@", storeURL, error);
        }

        if ( ![managedObjectModel isConfiguration: nil compatibleWithStoreMetadata: existingPersistentStoreMetadata] ) {
            if ( ![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL: storeURL error: &error] )
                NSLog(@"*** Could not delete persistent store, %@", error);
        } // else the existing persistent store is compatible with the current model - nice!
        NSLog(@"Existing store is compatible!");
    } // else no database file yet

    [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                              configuration:nil
                                                        URL:storeURL
                                                    options:nil
                                                      error:&error];
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

I get the logs "we have a persistent store" and "existing store is compatible", so I am assuming I am actually finding the core data model that is saved on the device.

This is my managedObjectModel:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.

    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Not Null!");

        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
   NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    return _managedObjectModel;
}
```

This is how I am trying to read the data (I am calling the method in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions):

```
-(void) readData {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if(context != nil)
        NSLog(@"not null");

    NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@ "StaffAccount"];

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSArray* results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (!results || error) { // nil is an error
        // handle error
        NSLog(@"Errore!");

    }

    NSArray *arr = [context executeFetchRequest:request error: &error];

    NSInteger count = [arr count];

    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)count);
}
```

Comment: I think the biggest thing that is throwing you off is `Existing store is compatible!`. That is getting logged in either case. I'd rewrite your first code block like this: https://gist.github.com/davbeck/8b72e51ee46b8ed44722912bd6e0b8f6. That will give you some better logging but it won't fix your underlying problem. Is the xcdatamodeld the exact same file or did you create it from scratch and duplicate the old model?

Comment: It's the exact same file. The problem I am noticing is that if I do a write operations from the second app and then read the core data. I see the entity has got 1 entry. Then when I open the first app, I can use it without any problem and even if I add more data, when I go back to the second app the entry is still 1. It seems, although they are exactly the same, they are using to different stores. The first project is 3 years old, has apple changed the store paths? Is that a possibility?

Comment: I have tried to do the exact same thing, with two different projects, with the same code I am using here and it works; so I am wondering if the problem is actually in the old app and if something has changed over the years?

Comment: You control where the store is written to. `[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Model"];` does that. I'm not sure what your applicationDocumentsDirectory method looks like, but if that is all the same it should match up. I was assuming that these 2 apps were using the same bundle id and that the second one was "2.0" type app, but if they are 2 different apps entirely they will be in different sandboxes. In that case, getting things like the documents or cache directory will return urls in 2 different sandbox directories.

Comment: I would print out the storeURL in both apps and see if they match. If you are running in the simulator, you can even open up the folder in Finder/Terminal and see what files are there. You can also examine the SQLite file directly either from the command line or with an app like [Base](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/base-sqlite-editor/id402383384?mt=12).